# Reset property page settings Visual Studio C 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, express

I made some changes to the Property Pages/Configuration Properties a long time ago and I'd like to reset them. I changed stuff like the output directory, code generation settings, etc.

I've tried resetting all environment settings from the Import and Export Settings Wizard. I've also tried the devenv /resetsettings command. Both of which did not work. Reinstalling doesn't work either. May I get some advice on how to restore everything back to the default.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to revert to old settings for the Project -> Properties.

This information is stored in the project itself, not in Visual Studio. Look for a file with the extension vcxproj in the solution folder.

You can edit it with Notepad (notepad++), or - you can edit it inside Visual Studio, by

- right-click the project, unload it, then edit project file, then reload project

Be careful how you edit these settings.

For best results, create a new solution, with a new project, and compare the settings from the newly created project with the existing one.

edit: on my computer (I have VS Ultimate I think, but it shouldn't matter):

To edit, go to Project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories, and on each, at the end of the line, press the arrow down, and click Edit...

VC++ directories:

```
$(VCInstallDir)bin
$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
$(WindowsSdkDir)bin
$(VSInstallDir)Common7\Tools\bin
$(VSInstallDir)Common7\tools
```

Include Directories:

```
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
$(WindowsSdkDir)include
$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include
```

from what I see in the directions you pointed out, all you have to do is remove from your list, the directories that you no longer want.

In c/c++ -> Code Generation ->

- enable minimal rebuild: NO

  - enable c++ exceptions: YES (/EHSC)
  - Basic Runtime Checks - Both
  - /MTd

...

General -> Output directory:
not sure what is the default, I would put something like

```
$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
```

Also, there seems to be a property sheet that may have been added to your project...

You can generally see the Property Manager from View -> Properties Window (F4).

here, you can expand the project configurations, and simply delete any property sheets you may not want (I expect a new project to have no property sheets).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I'm not too familiar with this. I just followed this site https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Windows and changed some of my Property Page settings. The problem is now every new project has the same settings. I'd like to restore the Property Page settings to whatever it was before but I don't quite know what they were.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help Mihaela. Those are the settings I wanted to revert. Much appreciated.