# VS2015 C++ Mistakenly erased "Include Directories" and "Library Directories" in VC++ Directories Property Page

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I recently installed VS2015 to look at a large library available online. As part of the set up it instructed to add boost to the Include and Library Directories in VC++ Directories in the properties for the solution. I mistakenly overwrote the fields instead of adding to them and these changes were saved. Now, predictably, nothing compiles. I don't know how to get them back to the original values, tried searching online for the values and have gone so far as to reinstall but boost is still the only thing in the fields.

I tried following [This simple "Hello World"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620919.aspx) tutorial and can't even compile this. Could somebody please provide the default values for these fields, or instructions on how to restore them to the defaults?

Edit: I have tried creating a new solution and the fields are also empty apart from the boost folders, see image. Indeed, I had tried the simple Hello World tutorial on a fresh install before posting.

[image: New Solution]

Comment: So create a new solution and copy/paste the missing values to your existing solution.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, see my edit. If I'm doing something incredibly stupid please tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by Step Solution:

1. Create a new project/solution.
2. *Add* the boost directories, don't overwrite.
3. Delete the older project, as it is virtually useless.

**EDIT**

(If the above didn't work. This is work Win32 Console Apps Debug Config x86)

Here are the default include directories:

```
$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);
```

Here are the default library directories:

```
$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);$(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x86
```

Comment: When I create a new solution it has the same issue.

Comment: You may have to uninstall Visual Studio. Take a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14700729/6525260)

Comment: Did you take a look at the answer link I posted, that tells how to reset everything?

Comment: I did. When I create a new solution, even after reinstalling, the same field values persist. The most recent time I uninstalled I manually deleted everything related to VC14.0 in C:\, %APPDATA%\local and %APPDATA%\roaming.

Comment: I know that this should not be the case. Believe me when I say that I have googled this extensively. I have come across many threads wishing for the kind of behaviour I am experiencing. I do not know why my VS is behaving this way.

Comment: It would help me greatly if you (or any other user) could please copy the values that you see in these two fields, removing your own additions. I have reinstalled VS2015 3 times. I tried downgrading to the community edition. I am at my wits' end and despite following all suggestions in responses and comments I am no closer to a solution and my post is at -3!

Comment: I will probably post that in the answer, but I cannot do it right now, as I am not on a Windows Computer.

Comment: @lampishthing I have (finally) updated my answer, to help you. Sorry for any time inconveniences, because as I mentioned, I was not on a Windows computer.