# How to restore default project settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, project

I have a big amount of projects in my solution, including csproj and vsxproj.
The issue is with C++ projects. They are not building properly due to bad configuration of project settings (output directory, include directories, linker output file, etc).

So, my question is how to restore the default project settings for all of my C++ projects?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned you could try to reset the integrated development environment (IDE) to a previous state using the `Import and Export Settings` wizard. For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[How to: Reset Your Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms247075(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

And you can also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700472/reset-property-page-settings-visual-studio-c-2010-express/14700729#14700729) to restore properties configuration.